# Using OpenGL instancing for rendering 2D scene with object depths and alpha blending

Tags: opengl

Here's what I'm trying to do: I want to render a 2D scene, consisting of a number of objects (quads), using instancing. Objects with a lower y value (towards the bottom of the screen) need to be rendered in front of the ones with higher y values. And alpha blending also needs to work.

So my first idea was to use the Z value for depth, but I soon realized alpha blending will not work unless the objects are drawn in the right order. But I'm not issuing one call for each quad, but use a single instanced call to render the whole scene. Putting the instance data in the correct sorted order seems to work for me, but I doubt this is something I can rely on, since the GPU is supposed to run those computations in parallel as much as possible.

So the question is, is there a way to make this work? The best thing I can think of right now is to issue an instanced call for each separate y value (and issue those in order, back to front). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instancing is best used for cases where each instance is medium-sized: hundreds or maybe thousands of triangles. Quads are not a good candidate for instancing.

Just build and render a sequence of triangles. There are even ways to [efficiently get around the lack of a `GL_QUADS` primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707766/734069) in modern OpenGL.

> Putting the instance data in the correct sorted order seems to work for me, but I doubt this is something I can rely on, since the GPU is supposed to run those computations in parallel as much as possible.

That's not how GPUs work.

When you issue a rendering command, what you (eventually) get is a sequence of primitives. Because the vertices that were given to that command are ordered (first to last), and the instances in that command are ordered, and even the draws within a single draw command are ordered, an order can be assigned to every primitive in the draw call with respect to every other primitive based on the order of vertices, instances, and draws.

This defines the [primitive order for a drawing command](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive_Assembly#Primitive_order). GPUs guarantee that blending (and logical operations and other visible [post-fragment shader operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing)) will respect the primitive order of a rendering command and between rendering commands. That is, if you draw 2 triangles in a single call, and the first is behind the second (with depth testing turned off), then blending for the second triangle will respect the data written by the first.

Basically, if you give primitives to the GPU in an order, the GPU will respect that order with regard to blending and such.

So again, just build a ordered stream of triangles to represent your quads and render them.

Comment: So I can actually rely on drawing order in an instance call? I know that wasn't your main point, but it's interesting.

Comment: About the stream of triangles, one main thing I was trying to achieve was minimizing the amount of data sent to the GPU. With instancing, I have one set of location/size/texture data for each instance, so those things are sent once for every 6 set of vertices. With the stream of triangles, I'll need to pass all of those for each vertex. I know my use case might not be that performance sensitive, but I'm trying to find the best way to do things, mostly as a practice.

Comment: @Elektito: "*With instancing, I have one set of location/size/texture data for each instance, so those things are sent once for every 6 set of vertices.*" Four vertices. You only need four vertices per quad. And the "location/size" is just part of the positions of each of the 4 vertices, so the only true per-instance data you have is the "texture".

Comment: But I need two triangles per quad, right? (I haven't used GL_TRIANGLE_FAN yet, but I guess with that I could make it 5). In my current code, I send one "index" value for each vertex, which is an integer from 0 to 3 and determines which vertex of the quad this is (0 for bottom-left, 1 for top-left, etc). The location, size and texture coordinates are all per-instance.

Comment: @Elektito: "*But I need two triangles per quad, right?*" And those two triangles share two vertices, so the total number of vertices for the quad is 4. Please see the answer I linked to for how quad topologies work. "*In my current code, I send one "index" value for each vertex*" You could more easily have computed this from `gl_VertexID`.

Comment: Isn't gl_VertexID deprecated?

Comment: @Elektito: No. Why would you think it was? OpenGL still has [built-in variables, plenty of them](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)). They only removed the OpenGL state-shadowing ones.

Comment: Must have gotten the wrong impression somewhere I guess. Anyways, SO is complaining that we shouldn't have extended discussions in comments. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks.